# Parametric Plot in different graphs

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

i would like to plot the function of a  parametric differential system below ideal in separate graphs. My code is

```
q0 = 80;
Γ = 4/3;
μ = 1/1000;
l = μ/2;
ε0 = b2*60;
ψ0 = 1/5;   
Rinit = 2/1000;
Finit = 12/10;
Δinit = 2;

smax = 1.5 10^-8;

 sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
 h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]* μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)]
 M0[s_] := Sqrt[Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)]
 sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)

  U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)

  G[s_] := M0[s]/Sqrt[U0[s]] 
  sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
  γ0[s_] := ε0/((q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)*h0[s]); 
  γu0[s_] := Sqrt[γ0[s]^2 - 1];
  γu1[s_] := Δ0[s] Sqrt[γ0[s]^2 - 1];


   Dsonic[s_] := h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3
  ndΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + Δ0[s]^Γ) 
  dF[s_] := (
  4 π R[s] (l^2 + R[s]^2) (h0[s]^2) (
  sG[s]^2) )/((l^2 + R[s] (R[s] - μ)) (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s])) ndΔ0[s] - 
  4 l^2 R[s]^3  μ + R[s] (-l^4 + R[s]^4) μ F[s]

  xmin = 3/10;
  xmax = 6/10;
  dx = 1/10;

sol3 = ParametricNDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == ndΔ0[s], 
R'[s] == Dsonic[s],  F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, {b2}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 32];
```

i am using parametric plot but apparently not correctly

```
ParametricPlot[
Evaluate@Table[{{(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*
              G[s]^2, (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
              G[s]^2) (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
              G[s]^2)} /. {R[s] :> R[b2][s], Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b2][s], 
              F[s] :> F[b2][s]}} /. sol3, {s, 0, smax}], {b2, 1, 2}, {x,xmin, xmax},
              AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I would like to get two graphs, not in the same plot, for two values of parameter b2.  b2=1 and b2=2;
Thank you

This is what it should look like but i can't do it using b2 as a parameter. I have just plotted with two different values saparetely

[image]

[image]

Top one is for b2=1
and bottom for b2=2

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = {(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*G[s]^2, 
        (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
        G[s]^2) (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*G[s]^2)} /. 
    {R[s] :> R[b2][s], Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b2][s], F[s] :> F[b2][s]} /. sol3;


Column @ 
  Table[
    Show[
      ParametricPlot[expr, {s, 0, smax}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
         BoundaryStyle -> None], 
      ParametricPlot[Evaluate[expr /. {x -> #} & /@ Range[.3, .6, .1]],
         {s, 0, smax}, 
         PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, Range[.3, .6, .1],
          LegendLabel -> "x"], {.42, .6}]], 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLabel -> PromptForm["b2", b2]],
     {b2, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"to get rid of the blue background..."***

```
Column @ 
 Table[
   ParametricPlot[Evaluate[expr /. {x -> #} & /@ Range[.3, .6, .1]], 
    {s, 0, smax}, 
    Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, Range[.3, .6, .1], 
      LegendLabel -> "x"], {.42, .6}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLabel -> PromptForm["b2", b2]], 
  {b2, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Any idea how to get rod of the blue background inside the graph?

Comment: @Agaph, please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

```
Column[
 Table[
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
    {(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*G[s]^2,
       (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
           G[s]^2) (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[
               s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*G[s]^2)} /. 
      {R[s] :> 
        R[b2][s], Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b2][s], 
       F[s] :> F[b2][s]} /. sol3],
   {s, 0, smax}, {x, xmin, xmax},
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["`` = ``", Subscript[b, 2], b2],
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  {b2, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems something is wrong. I upload two graphs of what it should look like for two different values of b2.

Comment: You have already received answers that address your comment. However, your question made no reference to anything other than the need for two separate plots. If you already had images of what you wanted, that should have been included in the initial question along with any desired modifications (e.g., remove filling). Answers are only as good as the question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe want an animation?

```
expr = {(2 (x - γu0[s]))/γu1[s]*
     G[s]^2, (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[
            s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*
        G[s]^2) (1 - (2 (x - γu0[s]))/(γu1[
            s] (R[s]^2 + l^2))*G[s]^2)} /. {R[s] :> 
     R[b2][s], Δ0[s] :> Δ0[b2][s], 
    F[s] :> F[b2][s]} /. sol3; 
draw[values_] := 
 Block[{b2 = 
    values}, {ParametricPlot[expr, {s, 0, smax}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All],
    ParametricPlot[
     Table[expr, {x, {.3, .4, .5, .6}}] // Evaluate, {s, 0, smax}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]} // Show]
```

```
{draw[1], draw[1.1], draw[2]}
Manipulate[draw[values], {values, 1, 2, .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: @kglr  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much